# Git fetch: The remote end hung up unexpectedly early EOF unpack-objects failed

Tags: git

when fetch a remote branch, I got error:

```
git fetch -v origin master

remote: Counting objects: 40, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

So I run `git gc` before it, or with `--aggressive` option, got the same error.

All the Git configuration related to the issue:

```
git config -l
core.compression=0
```

changed `core.compression` from -1 to 9, didn't work neither.

The new commits from the remote branch is not heavy, including a image with 2M.

Comment: What git remote -v returns? if it is ssh, try switching to https (or if https, try ssh)

Comment: @VonC I switched from ssh to https, it worked! thanks dud~

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it works fine, but once it goes wrong, get it every time.